# Thread interrupted exception when trying to BitmapFactory.decodeStream

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a class "ImageDownloader" created specially for list view. It get's imageView and url, and sets on this imageView bitmap from url. I did downloading bitmap in separate thread using AsyncTask:

```
    class ImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

    private String url;
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewWeakReference;

    // Getters
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    // Creator
    public ImageLoadTask(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        this.url = url;
        imageViewWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream();
            Bitmap finalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return finalBitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "exception in doInBackground " + url);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            result = null;
            Log.d("TAG","was cancelled "+url);
        }

        if (imageViewWeakReference != null && result != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewWeakReference.get();
            final ImageLoadTask imageLoadTask =
                    getImageLoadTask(imageView);
            if (this == imageLoadTask ) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And I have method which cancels previous downloads if necessary (for examle imageView has two imageLoadTasks and I need only last one) using method `imageLoadTask.cancel(true)`.

Everything works fine (application works and correctly shows bitmaps), but when I start appliaction i get exception

```
04-10 00:42:08.043      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex D/TAG﹕ exception in doInBackground http://avatars.yandex.net/get-music-content/dfc531f5.p.1080505/300x300
04-10 00:42:08.043      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
04-10 00:42:08.044      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.java:145)
04-10 00:42:08.044      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:73)
04-10 00:42:08.045      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
04-10 00:42:08.045      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:221)
04-10 00:42:08.045      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.flush(HttpConnection.java:141)
04-10 00:42:08.045      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.finishRequest(HttpTransport.java:52)
04-10 00:42:08.045      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:902)
04-10 00:42:08.045      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:788)
04-10 00:42:08.045      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:439)
04-10 00:42:08.045      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384)
04-10 00:42:08.046      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231)
04-10 00:42:08.046      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
04-10 00:42:08.046      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at leopikinc.musiciansyandex.ImageDownloader$ImageLoadTask.doInBackground(ImageDownloader.java:92)
04-10 00:42:08.046      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at leopikinc.musiciansyandex.ImageDownloader$ImageLoadTask.doInBackground(ImageDownloader.java:73)
04-10 00:42:08.046      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
04-10 00:42:08.046      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-10 00:42:08.046      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
04-10 00:42:08.047      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
04-10 00:42:08.047      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
04-10 00:42:08.047      583-645/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-10 00:42:08.347      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
04-10 00:42:08.349      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.java:145)
04-10 00:42:08.349      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:132)
04-10 00:42:08.349      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
04-10 00:42:08.349      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:50)
04-10 00:42:08.349      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource.read(HttpConnection.java:418)
04-10 00:42:08.349      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:349)
04-10 00:42:08.349      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
04-10 00:42:08.350      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:635)
04-10 00:42:08.350      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:611)
04-10 00:42:08.358      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:649)
04-10 00:42:08.358      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at leopikinc.musiciansyandex.ImageDownloader$ImageLoadTask.doInBackground(ImageDownloader.java:93)
04-10 00:42:08.358      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at leopikinc.musiciansyandex.ImageDownloader$ImageLoadTask.doInBackground(ImageDownloader.java:73)
04-10 00:42:08.358      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
04-10 00:42:08.358      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-10 00:42:08.358      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
04-10 00:42:08.358      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
04-10 00:42:08.358      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
04-10 00:42:08.359      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-10 00:42:08.359      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex D/skia﹕ ---- read threw an exception
04-10 00:42:08.360      583-648/leopikinc.musiciansyandex D/skia﹕ --- decoder->decode returned false
```

Also I sometimes get this exception when scroll ListView.

When I tryed downloading bitmap using deprecated methods like HttpClient there was no exceptions. Here is code when there is no exceptions

```
    Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {

    // AndroidHttpClient is not allowed to be used from the main thread
    final HttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");

    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode +
                    " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
            return null;
        }

        final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                entity.consumeContent();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "I/O error while retrieving bitmap from " + url, e);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Incorrect URL: " + url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url, e);
    } finally {
        if ((client instanceof AndroidHttpClient)) {
            ((AndroidHttpClient) client).close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and I call `downloadBitmap` on `doInBackgroud`

```
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        url = params[0];
        return downloadBitmap(url);
    }
```

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use an existing [image loading library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) for this, such as [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), rather than re-re-re-re-re-re-re-re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @CommonsWare I looked at it and I liked it but it's a task that I want to complete using only my code. It's an experience which will help me later

Comment: @Leopik the exception is throw because of an timeout. Try to increase the timeout limit.

Comment: @jonathanrz timeout of what? And how can I increase this timeout limit?

Comment: @Leopik timeout of your request. Probably you will be able to increase the timeout in the URL object.